# Heroku doesn't respect my ruby directive in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

At the top of my `Gemfile`, I have the following two lines:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.0'
```

However, run I run `git push heroku master`, I get the following message:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
```

Heroku doesn't let me specify `ruby 2.5.0`.

How can I go about telling Heroku that I want to use `ruby 2.5.0`?

Comment: Did you run bundle install locally after modifying the Gemfile and commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Yes! Oddly enough, restarting my computer seemed to have worked in getting heroku to see that i'm specifying ruby 2.5.0. I just installed the heroku toolset for the first time without restarting. Maybe that had something to do with it?

Comment: This maybe has something to do with rvm if you're using it to manage your ruby installations. Overall, I'm glad that you got things working.

Comment: I am using `rvm` to manage my ruby installations. Any precautionary measures I can take? Also, does heroku only look at my master branch when deciding if changes are created? I was using that a local branch to install heroku and configure it.

Comment: the documentation seems to be helpful: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions